# Microsoft Speaker Identification Algorithm

Tags: voice-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I've been developing application that used Speaker Recognition API by Microsoft especially Speaker Identification.

Is there any paper or journal that related to how Microsoft Speaker Identification works?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in algorithms it is better to read modern research on the subject, not specifically Microsoft papers. You can start with

[DEEP NEURAL NETWORK-BASED SPEAKER EMBEDDINGS FOR END-TO-END SPEAKER VERIFICATION by David Snyder, Pegah Ghahremani, Daniel Povey, Daniel Garcia-Romero, Yishay Carmiel, Sanjeev Khudanpur](http://danielpovey.com/files/2016_slt_xvector.pdf)

Which describes state of the art approach. Moreover, the code and models for the above is available in Kaldi project.